# Why is deciding NP deterministically exponential time

Tags: time-complexity, exponential, deterministic, np

From a textbook, it says:

> The best deterministic method currently known for deciding languages in NP uses exponential time. In other words, we can prove that
>   [image]
>   ...

Why is this true? I can't seem to find the intuition for this.

Comment: Not sure what "intuition" you're looking for, but ... when I imagine some classical NP problem (e.g. TSP), it seems obvious that you can always "systematically try all combinations" (which requires exponential time)...

Comment: May I'm just dumb. Is it possible that trying every combination will take an infinite amount of time? A roadblock for me understanding this is that this has to be true for every problem in NP, which I am not sure of.

Comment: This intuitive idea of "trying all combinations" is far from a real *proof*. But there's a large step between "finite" and "infinite". Or to put it that way: To be in NP, the solution must be verifiable in polynomial time, so we can only be talking about *finite* inputs anyhow. But maybe can give a real (and more profound) *answer* here.

Answer (score 3):

NP belongs to EXPTIME (though we're not sure whether or not it's a proper subset) because, intuitively, you can trace through all possible paths of a polynomial-time NTM in exponential time.

More concretely, consider any language L in NP. There has to be a polynomial-time NTM for it; let's call it M and say that it runs in nondeterministic time O(n<sup>k</sup>). For simplicity, we'll assume that the NTM only uses binary nondeterminism (i.e. at each step, it has at most two choices to pick from). This means that the maximum possible number of different branches of the nondeterminism is then given by 2<sup>O(n<sup>k</sup>)</sup>, and each one can be simulated in polynomial time by simulating the execution of the NTM on that branch. This means that the total time is poly(n) · 2<sup>O(n<sup>k</sup>)</sup> = O(2<sup>O(n<sup>k</sup>)</sup>), so this deterministic algorithm runs in exponential time.

Now, this doesn't mean that you *have* to spend deterministic exponential time to solve NP problems. It just says that if you want to use a deterministic algorithm, you need *at most* exponential time. The whole P versus NP question is about whether you can do better.

Hope this helps!